# JSON Loading Speed Optimization: Use online API vs. create my own API based on that?

Tags: json, rest, vue.js

I'm new to web development. I want to build a pet adoption website using existing API from the government just for practice. Current Site: https://pets.netlify.com/
p.s. I am using Vue

I've successfully loaded JSON data into my page. However, as you can tell the page take lots of time to load. This is part of my code to load JSON data.

```
mounted() {
  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://data.coa.gov.tw/Service/OpenData/TransService.aspx?UnitId=QcbUEzN6E6DL')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.pets = data;
  })
}
```

I tried to load the data using node.js, but it still takes super long time to load.

I am wondering if building my own API based on the given one can speed up the process? But the data updates every single day, so building an API doesn't seem to be a good option.

Or what can I do to speed up my page loading?
Any opinions would help!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can definitely help. If you cache the results in a smart way and don't load everything all the time it will have a beneficial influence. If you don't and you will just load everything as is all the time, then the chances are great that you end up having an API even slower than the original one.

Comment: Got it. I will definitely try that out! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If you think its answering your question then consider marking it as accepted answer.